# Concept of Race Conditions

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam, race-condition, on-duplicate-key

I know what a race condition is but I still don't fully understand:

Firstly, I know *myisam* does not support transactions and *innodb* does.

I am building a social site with a lot of users in mind and I wonder if I need to think about race conditions, because users will update their profile with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, but I wonder if a race condition will occur and how do you write code to protect against this issue?

Can someone please explain the concept of race condition on a site with multiple users e.g. use of COMMIT, ROLLBACK etc.

Where do I use these things?

Comment: What do you believe a race condition is? It seems you're misusing the term. Also, building a social networking site on MyISAM.. engine that scales worse than InnoDB once the data gets slightly larger - is it the best idea?

Comment: Think like this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition but apply it to code instead of electronics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Firstly, I know myisam does not support transactions and innodb does.

That's a good start.  I suggest using InnoDB.  Transactions are what make the modifications of a database [atomic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID#Atomicity) and consistent. Transactions also ensure isolation, so that no user of the database can interfere with the modifications of another user.

[Race conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) can occur when there is multithreading.  Yes, a database uses more than one thread, but transactions assure that one user's database changes are made before another user's database changes.  (Yes, that's a simplified logical explanation.)

Edited to add:  You can ask specific SQL question you might have in other Stack Overflow quesitons, but in general, you want to COMMIT as soon as possible after an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE SQL statement.

Comment: So would commit be this :

$query = mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM `users` WHERE `user_id`=".$_SESSION['user_id']);
COMMIT;

$query_result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
foreach ($args as $field){
 $args[$field] = $query_result[$field];

Comment: @Emmanuel Izu Onuoha: You don't have to COMMIT at all after a select.  You COMMIT after a transaction is completed, no matter how many INSERTS, UPDATES, and / or DELETES it takes to complete the transaction.

Comment: Sorry to ask stupid question..but if you say so then what is a transaction...because when a user logs-in or register or edit thier profile is that not a transaction...I i am building a site where users have profiles and write comments...so how do i do this..and i have 4 different files with SQL statments for Login,Register,edit profile and add comment...so honestly the concept isnt clear yet..